# Problem with HiDPI screen and FullHD monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdpi

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Inner monitor 3000x2000
External monitor 1920x1080
GPU - GeForce MX250
Driver: GP108BM

Windows can manage this setup, with Ubuntu it's not that simple.

I was trying to configure it in many different ways and two results were almost good but still not good enough.

I tried to configure it with use of xrandr - I used this command:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 3000x2000 --scale 2x2 --fb 3000x2000
```

and it finally came up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psKTe.jpg) but still on the external monitor everything was like really huge.

I heard about possible help with Wayland but it turned out I have some bug and I can't see gear icon on sign in screen - but that's not important.

I also tried to use Kubuntu (KDE Plasma) but it didn't work out.

Finally I ended up with setting up both screens to 100% with GUI and now on external monitor everything seems to be perfect but on laptop everything is so so tiny...

```
 xrandr --current
 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 2000, maximum 32767 x 32767
 eDP-1-1 connected 3000x2000+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 196mm  
   3000x2000     60.00*+  48.01  
 DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+516 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm

   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I don't really know how to fix that. Simples way would be scaling everything on 3000x2000 monitor 2 times but when I do scaling on one monitor then it automaticlly affect second one.

Comment: First, I suggest you edit your question and include the output of `xrandr`. Also let people know exactly what resolutions and scales you have set each of your screens to. And say what goes wrong or what settings are not available that you expect to be available.

Comment: Edited - I hope I didn't forget anything important